# My components are not being rendered when I click a link that should load them

Tags: reactjs

I'm confused as to why nothing happens when I'm clicking links in my app.

In my index.js file, I am loading my main screen called 'Game'.  Inside 'Game', I have two links, that when clicked, should render another screen.

In my index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Game from "./Game/Game";

ReactDOM.render(
<React.Fragment>
    <Game/>
</React.Fragment>,
document.getElementById('gameContainer')
```

)

In my index.html:

```
 <div>
    <div id="gameContainer"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="root"></div>
```

My Game.js:

```
import React from "react";
import CharacterStats from "../CharacterStats";
import DungeonStats from "../DungeonStats";

const characterStatsComponent = () => {
    return (
        <CharacterStats />
    );
}

const dungeonStatsComponent = () => {
    return (
        <DungeonStats />
    );
}

const Game = () => (
    <div>
        <a id="showCharacter" href="#" onClick={characterStatsComponent}>Show your character</a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <a id="showDungeon" href="#" onClick={dungeonStatsComponent}>Show current dungeon</a>
    </div>
);

export default Game;
```

The two other components, CharacterStats and DungeonStats are just a few bits of html and reactjs to show some data.

Neither CharacterStats or DungeonStats are loading when I'm clicking the links.

I am also getting no errors in the console.

Nothing happens when the links are clicked.

I also put this inside each onClick event:

```
    console.log('link was clicked');
```

And it does show the message in the console.  So that shows that it knows the link is being clicked.

Is there anything that would prevent them from being loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work because you are returning jsx into the onClick function context, and not into the Game component's return value.

You could define a state using useState, something like showDungeon and showCharacter that defaults to false, change it to true onClick, and in the Game component's return value add:

```
{ showDungeon && <DungeonStats /> }
```

Comment: I thought you couldn't use state in functional components?  I thought you needed it to be a class?  Thanks

Comment: Since react hooks came out, you can use state in functional components. Look up useState!

Answer (score 1):

React uses something called Synthetic Events to achieve cross browser event handling. If I understood your question correctly than changing the `onclick` to `onClick` should do the job for you.

Comment: I was hoping it was that easy, but it's still doing nothing.  Thanks though.